# Small question about derivative

Tags: analysis, derivatives

how to derive $\int_0^1 G(t,s) e(s)ds$ with respect to $t$

Where $G(t,s)$ is a Green function and $e:(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous and $e\in L(0,1)$

Please help me

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can commute the derivative and the integral operators in this case. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign).

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt}(\int_0^1 G(t,s)e(s) ds)=\int_0^1 \frac{\partial G(t,s)}{dt} e(s)ds $ it's right ?

Comment: yes, you are correct